# How do I get vim to stop complaining about missing colors?

Tags: vim

Vim's colors look good and everything seems to work fine, but at start up I consistantly get this error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>20_colorscheme..<SNR>20_highlight_do:
line    1:
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermfg=SeaGreen ctermbg=none
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg=Grey40
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg=Grey40
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This makes the boot up time for vim really long and I can't seem to fix it. `silent!` when setting the colorscheme doesn't work.

Furthermore grepping to try and see where the error comes from doesn't help either

```
 % grep -r "ctermbg=Grey40" ~/.vim/
 %
```

Any advice on where to start?

Comment: I'd suggest checking the files in /usr/share/vim or /etc/vim . . .

Comment: Which OS are you using? How is Vim installed on your system (i.e. did you do it manually or use a package/installer)?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you have a badly designed colorscheme file. For the `cterm*` color options I don't think Vim allows you to use color names like you can for the `gui*` color options. Which colorscheme are you using? Where did you obtain it?

Comment: zenburn, can't remember where I got it.

Comment: Patch 7.4.2182 addresses this issue: Problem: Color Grey40 used in startup but not in the short list.  Solution: Add Grey40 to the builtin colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the output of `:scriptnames`.  Whichever script is listed as #20 is the culprit, since the functions `<SNR>20_colorscheme` and `<SNR>20_highlight_do` are local to that script.  Or you could try grepping for "highlight_do".

Comment: `20: ~/.vim/plugin/colorsupport.vim`

removing this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some colorschemes require 256-color terminal. In my case the following command helped (before running `vim`):

```
export TERM='xterm-256color'
```